# present participle vs past participle into the other forms

Tags: present-participles

'I have an automatically moving toy car.'

moving car = car being moving

'I have a toy car moved by hand.'

moved car = car having been moved

Is it right?

Comment: Automatically moving = which moves [itself] automatically. Moved by hand = which has to be moved by hand.

Comment: @Kate Bunting I don't understand... Please translate them into phrases with participles!

Comment: @Kate Bunting I added the similar picture!

Comment: _A toy car moved by hand_ doesn't fit any of the examples using _broken_. If the car doesn't have a motor, it has to be moved along by the child using their hand to push it.

Comment: @Kate Bunting Sorry, but I think present participles show continuity, am I right? I mean is continuous form 'which is moving automatically' more appropriate?

Comment: Yes, the present participle _can_ mean that the action is happening at the present time (the car is moving), but as a description of the type of toy car, it means _capable of moving itself_.

Comment: @Kate Bunting Then, a past participle can mean capable of being moved? ex) paid app?

Comment: The participle _moved_ can mean _being moved_ or _capable of being moved_.

Comment: @Kate Bunting Thank you :)